# Get missing dates from table in Redshift

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift that has a Date column plus some other data:

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Value |
+------------+-------+
| 2016-09-25 |     1 |
| 2016-09-28 |     2 |
| 2016-09-29 |     3 |
+------------+-------+
```

I want to get the "missing" dates from this table. So, from the example above if I wanted to get all missing dates from 7 days ago until now, I'd like to produce a query that returns:

```
2016-09-22
2016-09-23
2016-09-24
2016-09-26
2016-09-27
```

I was try to use the generate_series(..) function to produce all dates, and then filter them out for what already exists in my table. So, something like:

```
    select CURRENT_DATE + i as MyDate
from generate_series(date '2016-09-22'- CURRENT_DATE, date '2016-09-29' - CURRENT_DATE ) i 
where MyDate not in (select [Date] from MyTable)
```

in this case i have the error "MyDate" does not exist. I've tried also using and EXCEPT clause which then produces the error:

```
INFO:  Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not supported.

[Err] ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Various other things I have tried produce that error, I can run generate_series(..) when its on its own but if i try it with any other clause etc it falls over.

Is this achievable in Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to find one work-around, which involves another way of generating a range of numbers without using generate_series(..). Not sure how performant it is, but this may help. Credit to the blog I found linked below. In their example I think they are suggesting to dump the numbers into a table and use that but below I just used a sub-query to show:

https://discourse.looker.com/t/generating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql-and-redshift/482

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - CAST ( days AS INT ) AS [Date]
FROM
 (SELECT 
    CAST (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5) AS INT) AS days
      FROM 
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
        (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5
WHERE (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5)) <= 7
)
EXCEPT
SELECT Date FROM MyTable
```

Note: in my original example I would only need to first 3 values (up to p3 in the select). This example will cover more/higher numbers

Comment: I need to go back 180 days, seems not possible with your solution right?

Answer (score 1):

Redshift does not fully support generate_series, and I have found that you can use it on its own but then the data it generates fails to combine in any way with any other redshift feature.

Your best option is to create a redshift table with one row per day, and to use that table in a join as follows

```
select date from dates_table
where date not in (select date from my_table)
```

There are sources available for this list of dates in a table, this table is often referred to as a date dimension, and is used within star schema data warehouses.

for example
[sisense date dimension](https://support.sisense.com/attachments/token/YsYjhrktrjyTeLaP6qVF4M5Ls/?name=Date%20Dimension.csv)

It may be just as easy to use excel for example to produce your list of dates, then save as a CSV

Use the redshift COPY command to load the dates in to a redshift table.

Comment: Ah okay was trying to avoid this but looks like there isn't much choice. I tried loading the dates into a temp table too but, as you say, if you combine it with anything - even an insert, it doesn't work

Comment: I have provided an answer that may be of interest :)